# Does restricting the range of a collection of nonempty sets to one dominated by the index set require the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The title was difficult to write, because it is hard to say the property I am looking for in words. Here it is in symbols:

$$\forall i\in I\ A_i\ne\emptyset\implies\exists X\preceq I\ \forall i\in I\ A_i\cap X\ne\emptyset$$

(Note that $X\preceq I$ means $X$ is dominated by $I$, i.e. there is an injection from $X$ to $I$.) Assuming the axiom of choice, this is easy: Pick a function $f$ on $I$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$ for each $i\in I$, and let $X={\rm ran}\,f$. Then $f$ is an onto function from $I$ to $X$, so applying ${\sf AC}$ again, we have $X\preceq I$, and of course $f(i)\in A_i\cap X$.

But the output of this theorem seems considerably less than the choice used to achieve it, and I can't seem to devise a way to get ${\sf AC}$ out of it, so I suspect it is weaker than ${\sf AC}$. Does anyone see how to (a) prove this without ${\sf AC}$, or (b) prove ${\sf AC}$ from this?

Comment: Both questions have the answer "It's very unclear", that's my guess. But it's very easy to come up with very hard choice principle, why did you come up with this one? (And since when $x$ denotes a member of $I$???)

Comment: (I'm asking because one can put in years of work in that sort of question without finding an answer. So before I set myself into this question, I would like to know where it came from...)

Comment: In the special case where the sets $A_x$ are one-element sets, your proposition reduces to a more familiar consequence of the Axiom of Choice, namely: if there is a surjection from $I$ to $X$, then there is an injection from $X$ to $I$. I don't know if this helps any; I just mention it in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: @bof: That's a nice remark. It points out that this principle implies The Partition Principle, and therefore cannot possibly be proved without the axiom of choice; it also points that it is going to be very difficult to prove that this doesn't imply the axiom of choice, if it is indeed doesn't imply the axiom.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It also implies that every well-orderable family of nonempty sets has a choice function. How close is that to the full Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @bof: Not very much. That only implies $\sf DC$, and not even $\sf DC_{\omega_1}$. I believe that this is also a consequence of The Partition Principle itself, but I'm not quite sure at the moment. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The source of this question is [this theorem](http://us2.metamath.org:88/mpegif/indexdom.html) on Metamath. I'm not how Jeff Madsen came up with it; but one of my past-times in Metamath has been eliminating gratuitous choice usage (now that Metamath also has ax-cc and ax-dc, to allow for more fine-grained indications of what kind of choice is really needed). For this one, nothing was really obvious, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila (Re: "since when does $x$ denote a member of $I$") I'm a bit rusty on the conventional usage here. What were you thinking? $\alpha\in I$? Or some other letter for the index set? In metamath, we just use $A$, $B$, $C$... for class variables and $x$, $y$, $z$... for set variables (in decreasing order of priority), regardless of context, with a few exceptions. It means less thinking ;)

Comment: As a result of the context of this question, the only information I can really make use of are the truth or falsity of "this is provable in $\Gamma$", where $\Gamma$ is one of ${\sf ZF}$, ${\sf ZF+CC}$, ${\sf ZF+DC}$, and ${\sf ZFC}$. I show that it is true for ${\sf ZFC}$, and from bof's remarks, I see that it is false for ${\sf ZF}$ and ${\sf ZF+CC}$, but ${\sf ZF+DC}$ is still open. Is that about right?

Comment: @Mario: $i$ goes into $I$ and $x$ goes into $X$. It's just basic common sense. It's like writing $n\in\Bbb R$. Sure, it's possible, but everyone knows that $n$ is a natural number and $x$ is a real number.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If I understand correctly, the Partition Principle (PP) says, "whenever there is a surjection from A to B, there is an injection from B to A", right? The OP's choice principle (OPCP) implies the ostensibly stronger statement (PP+), "for any surjective map $f:A\to B$ there is an injective map $g:B\to A$ such that the composite map $fg:B\to B$ is surjective", which is equivalent to the conjunction of PP and the statement, "for any surjective map $f:A\to B$ there is a map $g:B\to A$ such that the composite map $fg:B\to B$ is surjective." I tried but failed to prove that PP+ = OPCP.

Comment: (continued from previous comment) Is PP+ = PP? Is PP+ = OPCP? Is PP+ = AC? Is PP+ a known choice principle?

Comment: @bof: These are all good questions. Right now my brain is at the end of its rope (due to unfortunate decision to write my own code for Hebrew presentation in LaTeX, since Beamer fails when it comes to Hebrew). I will have to address them tomorrow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: On second thought, I think the proof of PP+ = OPCP is OK. The other questions remain: is it stronger than PP, is it weaker than AC, is it a known choice principle?

Comment: @bof I think it is worthwhile for you to put your discoveries in an answer, since you have made a lot of good observations. If you can find an answer to whether this is provable under ${\sf ZF+DC}$, I can accept it too.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I'm working on putting my comments in the form of an "answer", but it will not be a real answer that you can accept. I leave that to the experts on set theory.

Comment: @Mario: As pointed out, this principle **implies** $\sf DC$. And it implies much much more, if it's not going to be simple to prove its equivalence to the axiom of choice, then it is going to be unspeakably difficult to prove anything more about it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, the advantage of a reduction to known choice principles is that you can look up the relevant independence results. As you say, we know it implies ${\sf DC}$, so since ${\sf DC}$ is independent of ${\sf ZF+CC}$, clearly we can't prove it under ${\sf ZF+CC}$, but this doesn't mean that it's not a ${\sf DC}$-equivalent. From the formulation, I highly doubt it is a ${\sf DC}$-equivalent, but it's not necessary to prove ${\sf AC}$ from it if the target is merely ${\sf DC}$-unprovability. Is ${\sf \neg PP}$ consistent with ${\sf ZF+DC}$? That would also settle the question.

Comment: @Mario: **Every** model of $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$ that we know satisfies $\lnot\sf PP$. My ultimate goal is to prove that despite all that, the two are not equivalent, but this is far far far down the road.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In that case, the original question I set out to find an answer for is answered, although obviously there are still open questions regarding this and related choice principles, and although I am curious as to its resolution, I don't want to waste too much of others' time on a hard open problem, so I'll accept an answer. (If you prove something about the status of $\sf ZF\models PP\to AC$, you should write a paper on it, not post to some insignificant math.SE thread.)

Comment: @Mario: Of course. As for $\sf PP\not\rightarrow AC$, that's so far down the road that I'm not sure I'll even be on SE by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long comment rather than an answer. I can't answer either of your questions; all I'm going to do is restate your theorem in an equivalent but slightly simpler form. Maybe this will make it easier to find it in the literature. Consider the following statements.

(1) If $A_i\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$, then there is a set $X$ such that $|X|\le|I|$ and $A_i\cap X\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$. [Your theorem.]

(2) For any surjective map $f:A\to B$, there is an injective map $g:B\to A$ such that the composite map $fg:B\to B$ is surjective.

(2A) For any surjective map $f:A\to B$, there is a map $g:B\to A$ such that the composite map $fg:B\to B$ is surjective.

(2B) Whenever there is a surjection from $A$ to $B$, there is an injection from $B$ to $A$. [The Partition Principle.]

Without assuming AC, I claim that $\text{(1)}\Leftrightarrow\text{(2)}\Leftrightarrow\text{(2A)}\wedge\text{(2B)}$.

$\underline{\text{(1)}\Rightarrow\text{(2A)}}$: Suppose $f:A\to I$ is surjective. For $i\in I$ let $A_i=\{x\in A:f(x)=i\}$. By (1) there is a set $X$ such that $|X|\le|I|$ and $A_i\cap X\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$. Moreover, we may assume that $X\subseteq A$; then $f\restriction X$ is a surjection from $X$to $I$. Since $|X|\le|I|$, there is a surjection $g:I\to X$. Then $fg:I\to I$ is surjective.

$\underline{\text{(1)}\Rightarrow\text{(2B)}}$: Suppose $f:I\to B$ is surjective. For $i\in I$ let $A_i=\{f(i)\}$. By (1) there is a set $X$ such that $|X|\le|I|$ and $A_i\cap X\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$. It follows that $B\subseteq X$ and so $|B|\le|X|\le|I|$, i.e., there is an injection from $B$ to $I$.

$\underline{\text{(2A)}\wedge\text{(2B)}\Rightarrow\text{(2)}}$: Suppose $f:A\to B$ is surjective. By (2A) there is a map $h:B\to A$ such that $fh:B\to B$ is surjective. Let $C=h[B]$. Since we have surjections from $B$ to $C$ and from $C$ to $B$, it follows by (2B) and the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem that there is a bijection $g:B\to C$. Then $g:B\to A$ is injective, and $fg:B\to B$ is surjective.

$\underline{\text{(2)}\Rightarrow\text{(2A)}\wedge\text{(2B)}}$: Trivial.

$\underline{\text{(2A)}\wedge\text{(2B)}\Rightarrow\text{(1)}}$: Suppose $A_i\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$. Let $\hat{A}_i=\{i\}\times A_i$, and let$$A=\bigcup_{i\in I}\hat{A}_i=\{\langle i,x\rangle:i\in I,x\in A_i\}.$$For $\langle i,x\rangle\in A$, define $f(\langle i,x\rangle)=i$; then $f:A\to I$ is a surjection. By (2A) there is a map $g:I\to A$ such that $fg:I\to I$ is surjective. Let $C=g[I]\subseteq A$ and let $$X=\{x:\langle i,x\rangle\in C\text{ for some }i\in I\}.$$Since we have surjections from $I$ to $C$ and from $C$ to $X$, it follows by (2B) that there is an injection from $X$ to $I$, i.e., $|X|\le|I|$. Now it is easy to see that $A_i\cap X\ne\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$.

**P.S.** I don't know much about set theory, but I've been told that the Axiom of Determinacy (AD) is consistent with ZF+DC. If the Partition Principle (2B) were provable from ZF+DC, then it would be consistent with AD. However, AD implies that there is no injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb R$. On the other hand, inasmuch as there is a surjection from $\mathbb R$ to $\omega_1$, the Partition Principle implies that there **is** an injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb R$. Since the Partition Principle is incompatible with AD, it is not a theorem of ZF+DC, and *a fortiori* neither is your theorem.

Comment: You don't need AD to show that PP is not provable by DC, but yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks! I didn't think you needed DC. I almost added to my answer, "When the set-theorists wake up they will post the real proof, which has nothing to do with AD."

Comment: Hehe, yeah. I'll have to postpone that for later. I have finished the very nice essential barebones for my presentation thing. So now I'll have to sit and fill it with actual content.